# How to set react createtableselect to prevent creating element not in options?

Tags: reactjs, multi-select, create-table, react-select

I was trying to have a create select option that limit users from adding their own option to the predefine option list, Sample code for setting options in create table select.

Unfortunately this this doesn't solve the problem. please help with a simple fix

```
      <CreatableSelect
        name="dataN"
        id="dataN"
        className="selctInputs"
        placeholder="Select"
        isMulti
        onChange={(e) => getData(e)}
        options={Options} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ## React createtableselect prevent creating element not in option ##
'''    
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
    
 const createOption = (label, dataId) => ({
        label,
        value: dataId,
    });
    
    const levelOptions = ([{ "name": "Course1", "id": 1 }, { "name": "Course2", "id": 2 }, { "name": "Course3", "id": 3 }, { "name": "Course4", "id": 4 }])?.map((post, id) => {
        return createOption(post.name, post.id);
    });
 
        <CreatableSelect
          name="dataN"
          id="dataN"
          className="selctInputs"
          placeholder=" Select..."
          isMulti
          onChange={(e) => getData(e)}
          options={Options} />
'''
 
## Set isLoading to true provides a simple fix ##
'''    
    <CreatableSelect
      isLoading={true}
      name="dataN"
      id="dataN"
      className="selctInputs"
      placeholder=" Select"
      isMulti
      onChange={(e) => getData(e)}
      options={Options} />

'''
```